# Prolog- repeat input until

Tags: prolog, repeat

I want to create a predicate that only accepts a specific input from the user and it will keep asking for the right input if the user gives the wrong input.
I've created this, but its not completed because it does not ask for the new input if its wrong:

```
askchar(X):- write('give char'),nl, get_char(X), test(X).

test(X):- X=a, write('ok'). %accepts a
test(X):- X='1', write('ok'). %accepts 1
test(X):- write('wrong input. try again'),nl.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in systems lacking a decent tail recursive optimization, processing side effects can be conveniently done with a failure driven loop

```
1 ?- [user].
|: askchar(C) :- repeat, get(C), (C = 0'a ; C = 0'1, ! ; fail).
% user://1 compiled 0.07 sec, 2 clauses
true.

2 ?- askchar(X).
|: 5
|: a

X = 97 .
```

Comment: every time the user enters a wrong charater he should see the message "that char is not valid, enter a valid charater". That cut is a red cut? How can I use only green cuts in this predicate? Is it possible not to use the repeat predicate?

Comment: I have been around this for hours and cant find the solution!!

Comment: @mat: yes, I was referring to User' answer, after I upvoted it. Should be more explicit in my explanation, but writing English it's a bit of pain... I do prefer Prolog :). Anyway, in my old Prolog interpreter I had tail recursion, but *not* so decent...

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I got:

```
askChar(Char) :- get_char(Char), test(Char), write('This is the right char, thank you.'), !.
askChar(Char) :- write('That is wrong char!'), askChar(Char).    

test(s).
```

It asks again and again until the char `s` is typed in.

Comment: askChar(X) should return the char that passed the test. There has to be two accepted charaters and not just s. And every time the user enters a wrong charater he should see the message "that char is not valid, enter another character"